# Rails + PostgreSQL: grouping together with a sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by, sum, distinct

I have a table with this structure:

```
id | name      | batch_id | used
----------------------------------
1  | voucher 1 | 1        | 1
2  | voucher 2 | 1        | 0
3  | voucher 3 | 1        | 1
4  | voucher 4 | 2        | 0
5  | voucher 5 | 3        | 1
```

And I need to run a query that will group by batch_id and do a sum on the used column.

So the outcome that I need is:

```
batch_id | sum_used
----------------------------------
1        | 2
2        | 0
3        | 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
TableName.select('DISTINCT ON (batch_id) batch_id')
```

Which is the same as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (batch_id) batch_id FROM table_name
```

Grouping works but I can't get the sum to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `SUM` aggregation function:

```
SELECT batch_id, SUM(used::int) AS sum_used
FROM table_name
GROUP BY batch_id
ORDER BY batch_id;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46d1c/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║ batch_id  ║ sum_used ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║        1  ║        2 ║
║        2  ║        0 ║
║        3  ║        1 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

---

Alternatively using windowed function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT batch_id, SUM(used::int) OVER(PARTITION BY batch_id) AS sum_used
FROM table_name
ORDER BY batch_id
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46d1c/3/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way:

```
TableName.select('batch_id  as batch_id , sum(used) as sum_used').group(:batch_id)
```